# Python SQLite3 Commit() invalid error

Tags: python, sqlite

New to Python and first time using SQLite3.

I followed an online walk thru of how to use the basics of SQLite.  I'm trying to improve from my current CSV storage to a proper database and it seems simple enough.

My problem is that when I try and commit() spider says its an invalid syntax.
I searched for an answer but it seems that most folks have a slightly different version of my error.  I double checked brackets and I think I have them correct.
Can someone please lend a second set of eyes and tell me what I've missed?
Below is some of the code.  Omitted parts are just the serial port init stuff.  I can post that too if needed.

The basic idea of the code is that it reads a GPS puck and parses the NMEA sentences then stores them in a database along with a RSSI level I'm pulling from a radio.  The data_log is just so I can see it being printed on the screen in case it crashes.

```
def init_file():
    filename = raw_input('Enter save file:')
    global db
    db = sqlite3.connect('RSSI_DATA/'+filename)

    init_file()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, TOD BLOB,Lat REAL,Long REAL,Alt   REAL,Qual REAL,Ref_ID REAL,Num_Sat REAL,Hor_Dil REAL,RSSI REAL)
    ''')
    db.commit() #write header to db THIS ONE HAS NO ERRORS!!!

    while 1:

        gps = ser2.readline()
        try:    
            gps_msg = pynmea2.parse(gps)
        except:
            pass
        try:    
        if gps_msg.sentence_type == 'GGA':
            ser1.write("q")
            rssi = ser1.readline()
            rssi_dB = rssi_convert(float(rssi.strip('\0')))
            data_log = str(gps_msg.timestamp) + "," + str(gps_msg.latitude) + "," + str(gps_msg.longitude) + "," + str(gps_msg.altitude) + "," + str(gps_msg.gps_qual) + "," + str(gps_msg.ref_station_id) + "," + str(gps_msg.num_sats) + "," + str(gps_msg.horizontal_dil) + ","  + str(rssi_dB) + "\n"

            print data_log
            cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO users(TOD, Lat, Long , Alt, Qual, Ref_ID, Num_Sat, Hor_Dil, RSSI ) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''',(gps_msg.timestamp,gps_msg.latitude,gps_msg.longitude,gps_msg.altitude,gps_msg.gps_qual,gps_msg.ref_station_id,gps_msg.num_sats,gps_msg.horizontal_dil,rssi_dB)
            db.commit()  # THIS GETS AN INVALID SYNTAX ERROR???
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Please provide the stack trace of the exception you get from SQLite.

Comment: You forgot a `)` on the preceding line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the preceding line:

```
cursor.execute('''<insert>''',(<params>)
#             1               2        2?
```